# How do I display an image in JFrame from only a ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, image, stream, jframe, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a ByteArrayOutputStream representation of a JPEG image (although I could use GIF or PNG if that would work better). I would like to display this on the form, such as in a label or image object. I am constrained by the fact that I cannot write the image to a file, I can only ever store it in memory.

Comment: Pass it through `ImageIO`

Comment: *"..although I could use GIF.."*  Are they animated or static?  Don't use `ImageIO` for animated GIFs.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, they are static. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Cool.  The way suggested by m4tx would be best then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the (easiest) possibilites to solve the problem is creating a ByteArrayInputStream and then passing it to ImageIO:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// save the image to the output stream
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
```